# Is there a way to select a text field in code without clicking on it (javafx)?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, textfield, selecteditem

I am not sure how to or even if it is possible to select text fields in code. I could not find anything on the subject. If the is indeed a way to do so i have a template that could be modified to demonstrate how this could be done.

Here is the template/sample code:

Main class:

```
    package application;

    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.scene.Parent;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;


    public class Main extends Application {
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Main.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,600,400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

MainControl class:

```
    package application;

    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ResourceBundle;

    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

    public class MainControl implements Initializable {
@FXML
Button button;
@FXML
TextField field1;
@FXML
TextField field2;
boolean field1selected=true;
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {

}
public void switchTextFeild(ActionEvent event){
/*
The code for switch on witch TextField is selected would go here
*/
}
}
```

Main.fxml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
    <?import java.lang.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


    <AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.MainControl">
    <children>
    <TextField fx:id="field1" layoutX="6.0" layoutY="2.0" prefHeight="394.0" prefWidth="149.0" />
    <TextField fx:id="field2" layoutX="445.0" layoutY="2.0" prefHeight="394.0" prefWidth="149.0" />
  <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="177.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#switchTextFeild" prefHeight="95.0" prefWidth="239.0" text="Switch" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true">
     <font>
        <Font size="24.0" />
     </font>
  </Button>
  </children>
  </AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
field1.requestFocus();
```

in your `initialize()` method, so your `TextField` **field1** will be focused after your app is started. 
But notice, you have to wrap the `requestFocus()` call within a

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                field1.requestFocus();
            }
        });
```

because this should be done on the JavaFX Application Thread and not on the Launcher Thread, so if you would only call `field1.requestFocus()` this wont have any effect on our `TextField`.

Answer (score 2):

This is very simple

```
filedname.requestFocus();
fieldname.selectAll();
```

you have to first get the focus then use selectAll()function . if you will not use requestFocus() function then selectAll() will not work

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple for classic java. You can use code below for select text in a textField without doubleclicking on it (no idea about javafx).

```
field1.requestFocus(); 
field1.setSelectionStart(0);
field1.setSelectionEnd(field1.getText().length());
```