# JavaFX8 Is there a way to select text in DatePicker in code without clicking on it?

Tags: datepicker, javafx-8

Is there a way in JavaFX8 to select date (as text) in DatePicker from Java code? I want to activate a control with DatePicker in such a way, a user could edit a date without using a mouse.

The similar problem was described here [Is there a way to select a text field in code without clicking on it (javafx)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24821287/is-there-a-way-to-select-a-text-field-in-code-without-clicking-on-it-javafx), but the problem was about TextField.

I've tried the solution given in the above question:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            datePicker.requestFocus();
        }
    });
```

In result, the datePicker control is focused, but the text is not selected - typing a new date causes appending new characters to the default one.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hnot quite sure I understand what exactly you are after? The snippet above should request the initial (?) focus. DatePicker doesn't seem to auto-select all when getting focused, so you would have to call getEditor().selectAll in a listener to its focusedProperty.

Comment: date.picker.getEditor().selectAll does exactly what I am looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has been solved according to [kleopatra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203657/kleopatra)'s hint in the following way:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        datePicker.requestFocus();
        datePicker.getEditor().selectAll();
    }
});
```

Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code after calling `stage.show();`:

```
datePicker.getEditor().requestFocus();
datePicker.getEditor().positionCaret(0);
datePicker.getEditor().selectNextWord();
```

Comment: a couple of comments: a) there's a selectAll method b) you might want to do the selection inside a listener to the focusedProperty _and_ wrap it into a Platform.runLater to overrule internal settings